# How to override SortedList Add method for sorting by value

Tags: c#, sorting, overriding, sortedlist

I have a `SortedList` in my code. I fill inside it key value pairs. When I add an item to `SortedList` it sorts automatically by key. But i need to sort it by value. Because the values are visible texts in a combobox. They must be alphabetically sorted. I decided to write a class and inherit from `SortedList` class and override the `Add` method.

But when I looked at the code of [Microsoft's SortedList class](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/SortedList@cs/1305376/SortedList@cs), I see there is an `Insert` method and it makes the sorting and unfortunately it is private so I cannot override it. Can you help me about this?

Note: I cant use `ArrayList` or `Dictionary` or something else. I cannot manage all code in our project. I have to return '`SortedList`' or '`MySortedList`' derived from `SortedList`

Comment: Do you have any requirements on what the keys must be? If not, why not just add your text as both the key and the value? `sortedList.Add(text,text)`

Comment: Yes the first parameter has to be key and the second one has to be value. It depends on other classes in our project

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Sorted List by Value with Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649481/c-sharp-sorted-list-by-value-with-object)

Comment: `Insert` method ought to be private because it makes no sense to insert something at a particular position in a collection that has its own order (sorted order). Better implement a custom collection that holds both a dictionary (for keyed access) and a sortable collection (like List<T>) to remember order. You will get a sample implementation in the question I linked above. Goodness me, dont use reflection for this, that too on code you dont own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion was to use a custom comparer but his didn't solve the problem. I therefore investigated SortedList implementaion more detailed and replaced my original post with the following suggestion:

Overriding the Add method and invoke the private Insert using reflection should do the trick

```
private MySortedList()
{
}

public override void Add(object key, object value)
{
    if (key == null || value == null)
    {
        //throw new ArgumentNullException("key", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_Key"));
        throw new ArgumentNullException(); // build your own exception, Environment.GetResourceString is not accessible here
    }

    var valuesArray = new object[Values.Count];
    Values.CopyTo(valuesArray , 0);

    int index = Array.BinarySearch(valuesArray, 0, valuesArray.Length, value, _comparer);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        //throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_AddingDuplicate__", new object[] { this.GetKey(index), key }));
        throw new ArgumentNullException(); // build your own exception, Environment.GetResourceString is not accessible here
    }

    MethodInfo m = typeof(SortedList).GetMethod("Insert", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    m.Invoke(this, new object[] {~index, key, value});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example code to write my own comparer?

Comment: We are talking about classic SortedList, not the generic SortedList<T,TV>, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this will work. The custom comparer only gets to see the keys from the `SortedList`, not the values.

Comment: My comment above applies to the [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13415063/1) of the answer. The new version looks like it might work.